# How to include a different library based on processor in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an Xcode project that is 5 years old.. the project uses a custom library that is only compiled for 32 bit processors.. The project is deployed only via adhoc installations and there was no need for changing the custom library.

Today the company purchased a set of new ipads that have a 64 bit processors, therefore we had to recompile the library for arm64.

Re-included the new library in the project, and compiled for the new ipads.. and everything was perfect.

However, as expected, the project will not compile now for 32 bit ipads.

I would like to know how to link a custom library based on the processor.. I donno if I have used the proper keywords but I have already searched on this site and have found answers to do it based on (simulator/device) or even by sdk but not by processor..

example: 
if processor is 32 bit use: files32/library.a 
if processor is 64 bit use: files42/library.a

Thanks

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27511151/create-32-bit-and-64-bit-static-library-for-devices-and-simulators-xcode

Comment: hi roman.. i already dropped on this post as well.. but, i don't have the code for the library.. i was just provided with 2 versions of it 32 bit and 64 bit.. i don't need a fat library.. what i need is actually a way to let xcode to automatically use the appropriate file depending on the prcoessor! can that be done?

Comment: I believe the easiest thing for you to do is to combine the 64 and 32 bit versions of the library into a single file using `lipo`, then link against that. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763020/can-i-build-both-32-bit-and-64-bit-architectures-of-a-library-on-mac-os